# Trying to prevent user from entering a non-number or a number above a certain range

Tags: javascript

Here's what I have so far but the problem is if I enter the number 16,it won't allow me to change what's in the text box anymore. Looking for help on how to fix that,thanks guys.

```
 <SCRIPT language=Javascript>
  <!--
  function isNumberKey(evt)
  {
     var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
     if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
        return false;
      var num = document.getElementById('quantity').value
         var y  = parseInt( num  ,  10  ) 
         if ( y > 15 )
         return false;

         return true;
     }
 </SCRIPT>


<form action="RegServlet" method="post">
    <p>
        Enter quantity you would like to purchase  :  <input name="quantity" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" id ="quantity" size=15 type="text" value="1"/>
    </p>
</form>
```

Comment: You're missing a semicolon after getElementById line, and the line after that too

Comment: `<input type="number" min="1" max="15">`?

Comment: @FranciscoAfonso http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/

Comment: and bad style is by choice. ;)

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: it can be optional and by choice but it is still bad.

Comment: @FranciscoAfonso Please explain how its bad.

Comment: the input type did also not work

Comment: @user2323975: Why not? Of course you need to remove that event listener that prevents pressing keys.

Comment: +1 @Bergi for rocking HTML5 number input type.  You should be able to drop the entire script block and event listener unless you want your code to be able to capture without focus on the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible solution, I have removed your inline event handler in favour of assigning it with [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener)

I have also changed from using the `keypress` [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event) to `keyup`

I am stripping, with a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions), any non-numeric characters regardless, not bothing to check what was pressed.

We [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) the `value` of the input element and if this number is greater than specified, we [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) off the last character entered.

HTML

```
<p>Enter quantity you would like to purchase :
    <input name="quantity" id="quantity" size=15 type="text" value="1" />
</p>
```

Javascript

```
var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity");

function verify(evt) {
    var target = evt.target;

    target.value = target.value.replace(/[^\d]/, "");
    if (parseInt(target.value, 10) > 15) {
        target.value = target.value.slice(0, target.value.length - 1);
    }
}

quantity.addEventListener("keyup", verify, false);
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/7ALr2/)

Wrapping the whole thing up in a [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onload) event.

> Notes
>
> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At
>   this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all
>   the images and sub-frames have finished loading.

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    document.getElementById("quantity").addEventListener("keyup", function (evt) {
        var target = evt.target;

        target.value = target.value.replace(/[^\d]/, "");
        if (parseInt(target.value, 10) > 15) {
            target.value = target.value.slice(0, target.value.length - 1);
        }
    }, false);
});
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/7ALr2/)

Comment: It is working for me on jsfiddle but not on my web page.Here is the full web page.Any ideas?Really appreciate this by the way.Its crunch time on this assignment ha http://chopapp.com/#16nu6lzt

Comment: You probably need to wrap your javascript in a window.onload event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onload

Comment: That works thanks alot!Now to drink another coffee so I can stay awake until 6am to get this done ha